# How to generate pojos from multiple xsd with cxf-xjc-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, cxf, xjc

I'd like to use the maven `cxf-xjc-plugin` plugin to java classes from `xsd` files. I have approx 30 xsd files, which I'd have to link explicit each of them inside `xsdOptions`.

Is it possible to provide wilcard matching for this plugin to generate from any xsd files found?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately, this plugin forces the developer to write the path for each XSD. You can't use a wildcard for specifying the path to XSD files.

However, there has been an undocumented update made to the plugin that allows to specify a directory instead of a list of files. As such, if all of your XSDs are inside the same directory, you can specify this. I tracked the changed to [this email](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-commits/201507.mbox/%3C8c553532858d4428b19c6af2fd9dbc39@git.apache.org%3E) from the cxf-commits mailing list, dated July 2015, from `dkulp@apache.org`:

> Convenience option for configuring the code generation from XSD files:
>   Instead of having to explicitly list every single file using the `<xsd>`
>   element, now the new `<xsdDir>` element can be used instead for
>   specifying a directory. From this directory all `*.xsd` files will be
>   used for code generation.

This attribute [is not documented](https://cxf.apache.org/cxf-xjc-plugin.html) but you can find it [in the source code](https://github.com/apache/cxf-xjc-utils/blob/xjc-utils-3.0.5/cxf-xjc-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/maven_plugin/XsdOption.java#L27) for version 3.0.5 for example.

You could then have the following configuration:

```xml
<xsdOption>
  <xsdDir>/path/to/directory/having/all/XSD</xsdDir>
  <!-- rest of configuration -->
</xsdOption>
```

Do note that, from reading the source code, the search for XSD files is not recursive: all XSD must be placed inside this directory and not into subdirectories for the plugin to find them.

Comment: Excellent research. This was a fantastic solution for me.

Comment: This shit is good. You saved me a day. I mean thanks for explanation and working solution.

Comment: Can I add multiple xsdDir?